# autoscraper library not capturing null values when scraping a webpage

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

I'm trying to build a dataframe from two different categories of a website's data using [autoscraper](https://github.com/alirezamika/autoscraper) library.

```
import pandas as pd
from autoscraper import AutoScraper
df=pd.DataFrame()

#scrape data
url = "https://www.grabon.in/makemytrip-coupons/"
list_1 = ["Flight Tickets - Get Up To Rs 1250 OFF", "Rs.3000 OFF"]
scraper = AutoScraper()
df["description"] = scraper.build(url, list_1[0])
df["amount saved"] = scraper.build(url, list_1[1])
```

One of the categories, "amount saved" seems to have missing values corresponding to "description" category. Hence the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Samhitha/Desktop/Sam-GrabOn/readibility/TEXTHERO_py.py", line 9, in <module>
    df["amount saved"] = scraper.build(url, list_1[1])
  File "C:\Users\Samhitha\Desktop\Sam-GrabOn\PycharmProjects\kw_rank_GWT_Emailers\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3163, in __setitem__
    self._set_item(key, value)
  File "C:\Users\Samhitha\Desktop\Sam-GrabOn\PycharmProjects\kw_rank_GWT_Emailers\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3239, in _set_item
    value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)
  File "C:\Users\Samhitha\Desktop\Sam-GrabOn\PycharmProjects\kw_rank_GWT_Emailers\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3896, in _sanitize_column
    value = sanitize_index(value, self.index)
  File "C:\Users\Samhitha\Desktop\Sam-GrabOn\PycharmProjects\kw_rank_GWT_Emailers\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 752, in sanitize_index
    "Length of values "
ValueError: Length of values (171) does not match length of index (173)
```

Is there a way to get autoscraper capture null values for "amount saved" appropriately corresponding to its "description" so that I can append both of them into a single dataframe?

Comment: I'm too facing similar kind of issue. Is there any work around to fix this issue?